# Convert class to parameters map in REST Assured

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have the following class:

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val surname: String,
    val age: Int
}
```

and I want to do this:

```
val person = Person("John", "Locke", 66)

Given {
    params(person)
} When {
    post("/api/example")
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work, because `params()` needs a Map.

I would like to be able to do something like what you can do with JSONs:

```
@Serializable
data class Person(
    @JsonProperty("name")
    val name: String,
    @JsonProperty("surname")
    val surname: String,
    @JsonProperty("age")
    val age: Int
}
```

```
val person = Person("John", "Locke", 66)

Given {
    body(person)
} When {
    post("/api/example")
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The class that you are trying to convert to map, does it have only primitive types and strings or can it also have a list, map or another data class inside?

Comment: @ArpitShukla It can have also lists or other classes.

Comment: @ArpitShukla List in particular; I can avoid using other classes if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rest-assured java documentation, it doesn't have an interface to pass an object as argument for `params`

ref - https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html

aviailable params interfaces

```
RequestSpecification params(String firstParameterName,
                            Object firstParameterValue,
                            Object... parameterNameValuePairs)
```

and

```
RequestSpecification params(Map<String,?> parametersMap)
```

Seems map is the only way here, we could do a workaround for this by converting object to map

you could use approaches mentioned here for converting data class to map - https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/data-class-to-map

Please let me know if you need any help on any of the appoaches

Comment: It doesn't work with parameters, and this is what my question is about.

Comment: thanks for the input @USER, will update the answer accordingly